# Adjusting brightness and contrast for indexed images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, brightness, contrast, indexed-image

I am changing the image brightness for an indexed image in MATLAB. For that I created `m`, a 3x256 ones matrix, then I multiply it with a number, then I add `m` to `x` (the map for my image). My question now how to return one if the result is bigger than one.

```
[im3,x]=imread('corn.tif');
m=ones(256,3)
m=m.*50
[im33 c]=deal(im3,x+m)
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo im changing image brightness for indexed image in matlabfor that i created m a 3*256 ones matrix then i multiply with a number then i add m to x (the map for my image) my question now how to return one if result bigger than one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting values in the array `x` larger than the value `a` to `a` is variously called clamping, clipping or saturating. The simplest method is using `min`:

```
x = min(x,a);
```

For example, given your color map `x`:

```
[im3,x] = imread('corn.tif');

subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(im3,x)

x = x + 0.2;
x = min(x,1);

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(im3,x)
```